# Python: Reading Excel and automatically turning a string into a Date object?

Tags: python, excel, parsing, openpyxl

I'm using the `openpyxl` library in Python and I'm trying to read in the value of a cell. The cells value is a date in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`. I would like for the value to be read into my script simply as a string (i.e. `"8/6/2014"`), but instead Python is somehow automatically reading it as a date object (Result is `"2014-08-06 00:00:00"`) I don't know if this is something I need to fix in Excel or Python, but how do I get the string I'm looking for?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out how to fix it with these lines of code:

```
dateString = str(ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value.date())
newDate = datetime.strptime(dateString, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

The string "newDate" gives me the format "8/6/2018"

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing it in your Excel if you want to preserve what is being read in by `openpyxl`. That said, when a cell has been formatted to a date in Excel, it becomes altered to fit a specified format so you've lost the initial string format in either case.

For example, let's say that the user enters the date `1/1/2018` into a cell that is formatted `MM/DD/YYYY`, Excel will change the data to `01/01/2018` and you will lose the original string that was entered.

If you only care to see data of the form `MM/DD/YYYY`, an alternate solution would be to cast the date with `date_cell.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: date_cell.strftime doesn't work for me, is there a library or something I should import?

Comment: I figured it out, I'm posting my solution as the answer to my own questing now. I think it should be something else besides date_cell?

Comment: `date_cell` is just an example name